# Crash while using ffmpeg4android using Galaxy s6 edge device

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am using ffmpeg4android_lib to compress video in my android application, it is working in almost all testing devices but it does not work in Galaxy s6 edge and Galaxy s7 edge.

my code as following :

```
String inputFile = FileManager.getInstance().getRealPathFromVideoUri(context, video);
Log.i("INPUT FILE PATH", inputFile);

LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
try {
        String workFolder = context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        String outputFile = FileManager.getInstance().getFileFullName(ForSaleConstants.VIDEO_FOLDER,
        String.format(ForSaleConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_FORMAT,      ForSaleConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_NAME_PREFIX, System.currentTimeMillis()));

        String complexCommand[] = {
            "ffmpeg", "-y"
            , "-i", inputFile
            , "-strict", "experimental"
            , "-s", "320x240"
            , "-r", "25"
            , "-aspect", "4:3"
            , "-ab", "48000"
            , "-ac", "2"
            , "-vcodec", "mpeg4"
            , "-movflags", "+faststart"
            , "-ar", "22050"
            , "-b", "2097k"
            , outputFile};
            vk.run(complexCommand, workFolder, context.getApplicationContext());
            Log.i("OUTPUT FILE PATH", outputFile);
            return outputFile;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        ForSaleServerManager.getInstance().logAndroidError("Couldn't compress video file");
        return null;
    }
```

The crash as following :

```
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libloader-jni.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
at com.netcompss.loader.LoadJNI.<clinit>(LoadJNI.java:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest version solves this issue
Download from here:
androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved when I add the following line to build.gradle file

```
ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
```

for some reason it was not able to load the library files and it solved when adding previous line.